# Highcharts align data label based on positive / negative value

Tags: highcharts

I'm generating a bar chart and currently all data labels are aligned to the right.

For positive values, I would like the data label aligned to the right of the bar and for negative values I would like the data label aligned to the left of the bar.

How can I achieve this?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania']
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'right',   
                    inside: true
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [107, 31, 635, -203, -300]
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tf2khzh2/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably quite a few ways to do this. One way is setting point specific `dataLabels` objects. Depending on the size of your data this could be done directly on the series data, like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tf2khzh2/2/)):

```
series: [{
    data: [107, 31, 635, { y: -203, dataLabels: { align: 'left' } }, { y: -300, dataLabels: { align: 'left' } }]
}]
```

Or you could for example use the callback function when initializing the chart to loop over your series and set it in the same way, like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tf2khzh2/3/)):

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: [107, 31, 635, -203, -300]
    }]
    // ...
}, function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.series.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < this.series[i].points.length; j++) {
            var point = this.series[i].points[j];

            if(point.y < 0) {
                point.update({ dataLabels: { align: 'left'} }, false);
            }
        }
    }

    this.redraw();
});
```

An alternative approach which I will only describe is using several series, one for positive and one for negative, and then [link them](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cbar%3E.linkedTo) and use different `align` specifications for each series.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Halvor Strand. I initially tried the callback method but this then broke my export (only displayed positive values in the graph!) so had to change to using point specific datalabels.